# Angular sticky footer no longer sticky, if within the app.component

Tags: css, angular, footer

I want to create a sticky footer that sticks at the bottom if the content height is less than the view port, and moves down if the content height is greater than the view port. (right side of the image) It works the way I want with the following code:

My index.html:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main Content</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My styles.css:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #ff7e7e;
}
```

However, it no longer works when I move the footer to the app.component. The result looks like on the left side of the image.

My changed index.html:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main Content</main>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.component.html:

```
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

My app.component.css:

```
footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #ff7e7e;
}
```

I think there's a problem with the encapsulation. Anybody got any ideas?

[image]